# Anonymously function call in WCF service with message security mode

Tags: wcf, function, authentication, anonymous

I've created a WCF service, with a WSDualHttpBinding. The security mode is not specified, so it is set to WSDualHttpSecurityMode.Message.

It works fine, connecting from a client to the server with a credential, that is allowed.

When I connect to a server with credentials, that are not allowed, I get a SecurityNegotiationException.

Thats all fine, what I now want to do, is that there is one function in the service, that is allowed to be called anonymously.

So I want to try to call the service and when my credential are not allowed, I want to call a function called GetDescription() that will return me a description of the service.

The reason is, that we are hosting some services and will discover them by broadcast. If there is a service, that the client is not allowed to, I want to see some details from the service, to overcome this issue, by reconfiguring the service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Authentication is executed long time before any of your operation so with out of the box functionality it is not possible because exception is fired before WCF even knows what operation user called.  Executing operations based on user "permissions" belongs to authorization and it is done only for authenticated users. Cheating WCF to allow that as you want to do it now would require some modification of security pipeline and excluding selected SOAP actions from authentication (I'm actually not sure how to do that).

What type of authentication are you using? If you have default configuration you should have Windows based authentication and then simply your users must call your service when logged in with valid AD account.

Btw. why are you doing custom discovery when [WCF offers its own](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456782.aspx)? You should use the same mechanism as WCF discovery does - expose separate unsecured endpoint for discovery.

Comment: At the moment there are only services with Windows based authentication, but in the future there will be some services with custom authentication too. So that I first want to try to connect with Windows based authetication and when this will fail, I want to ask the user for credentials and want to try to connect to the service with these credentials.

At the time, when I am asking the user for credentials, I want to show some details data about the service, so that the user can identify the service easier, because there will be more than one service running on the same machine.

Comment: I guess it will require complete replacing of WCF authentication mechanism. This is usually done simply by exposing two endpoints - one internal for windows authentication and one external for user name authentication. What you are trying to do is mostly outside of WCF / web services scope.

Comment: I think you are right. Maybe I have to offer two wcf Services. One secure and one none secure to offer the description.